# Error: Type error when trying to assign a value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to specify a ref for input, but the compiler swears at an error like textInputRef. I can't figure out what the type should be.

```js
private place: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement> = React.createRef();
private description: React.RefObject<HTMLTextAreaElement> = React.createRef();
```

```js
<FormText textInputRef={this.place}>Name of place</FormText>
<FormText textInputRef={this.description} area>
```

```js
type FormTextProps = {
  textInputRef?: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>;
};
```

```js
render() {
    const { textInputRef } = this.props;

    const InputElement = area ? 'textarea' : 'input';

    return (
      <label>
        <InputElement
          type="text"
          ref={textInputRef}
        />
      </label>
    );
  }
```

Error on "ref":

```
Type 'RefObject<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement> | undefined' is not assignable to type '((string | RefObject<HTMLTextAreaElement> | ((instance: HTMLTextAreaElement | null) => void)) & (string | RefObject<HTMLInputElement> | ((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void))) | null | undefined'.
  Type 'RefObject<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>' is not assignable to type '((string | RefObject<HTMLTextAreaElement> | ((instance: HTMLTextAreaElement | null) => void)) & (string | RefObject<HTMLInputElement> | ((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void))) | null | undefined'.
    Type 'RefObject<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>' is not assignable to type '((instance: HTMLTextAreaElement | null) => void) & RefObject<HTMLInputElement>'.
      Type 'RefObject<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>' is not assignable to type '(instance: HTMLTextAreaElement | null) => void'.
        Type 'RefObject<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>' provides no match for the signature '(instance: HTMLTextAreaElement | null): void'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: `React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement> | React.RefObject<HTMLTextAreaElement>`

Comment: I tried like this, but the error still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prop `textInputRef` is open to receive either a `RefObject<HTMLInputElement>` or a `RefObject<HTMLTextAreaElement>`, but an actual element can only use it's appropriate type, not the other.

E.g. you might pass a `RefObject<HTMLInputElement>`, but `area` might be `true` at the same time, so you would ask to assign `<textarea ref={ HTMLInputElementRef } />`, which is obviously not allowed.

You need to specify which component type to render and which ref type to assign "at the same time", i.e. they should be strongly related.

As `textarea` and `input` are completely different components, which have different attributes *(e.g. `type="text"` is also not valid for the `textarea`)*, I'd suggest to render the whole component conditionally, instead of specifying only the component name conditionally:

```jsx
<label>
    { area
        ? <textarea ref={ textInputRef as React.RefObject<HTMLTextAreaElement> } />
        : <input type={'text'} ref={ textInputRef as React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement> } />
    }
</label>
```

Note that I would generally *not* recommend to use the `as` keyword, but I would justify it's usage here, because you can be sure that e.g. a `ref` of a `textarea` always is - by definition - a `React.RefObject<HTMLTextAreaElement>`. *(Correct me if I'm wrong)*

Comment: I fix this only change a ref on InputElement such as:  ref={textInputRef as React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement & HTMLTextAreaElement>}. Thank for your answer)

Comment: It doesn't show an error, but I'd say that is effectively the same same as just adding `@ts-ignore` above that line. You insist that `textInputRef` is both a `HTMLInputElement` and a `HTMLTextAreaElement`, which is never really true.